# How to determine the best query,among these to make sure it executes in minimum time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

The query is

```
 create table domestic
 (
     salesid int, saleamt money
 )

 create table international
 (
     salesid int, saleamt money
 )

 insert into domestic values(1,200),(2,400)
 insert into international values(4,500),(6,800)

 --to get the difference
--1
 select count(salesid),sum(saleamt) from domestic
 union all
  select count(salesid),sum(saleamt) from international
--2
  select count(salesid),sum(saleamt) from
  (
  select salesid,saleamt from domestic
  union all
   select salesid,saleamt from international
   )x
```

I have included the execution plan for these. And checked the `statistics`

[image]

[image]

The result from `set statistics io on;`

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Table 'international'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'domestic'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'international'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'domestic'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Can somebody help me in deciding which will execute in minimum time?

Comment: You should try both queries using millions of rows.

Answer (score 3):

The queries are not equivalent (produce different results) so not really useful to compare them.

In any case I think you would need to have a lot more data in the tables to have a meaningful test.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to find execution times and compare them.

Comment: It gives `SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.` for 'em both

Comment: Well that's because you have just few records. What else do you expect. Try with at least thousands.